# ip2location module to get HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR instead of REMOTE_ADDR

Tags: c++, c, apache

I am using ip2location, and for my sites not behind a load balancer it works fine.

Anything that is behind a F5 or AWS ELB, it returns empty string

I started to look at the module for ip2location and was trying to change it so it would get the X_FORWARDED_FOR instead.

Here is the mod_ip2location.c

```
#include "httpd.h"
#include "http_config.h"
#include "http_protocol.h" 
#include "http_log.h"
#include "ap_config.h"
#include "apr_strings.h"
#include "IP2Location.h"


static const int ENV_SET_MODE    = 0x0001;
static const int NOTES_SET_MODE  = 0x0002;
static const int ALL_SET_MODE    = 0x0003;

typedef struct {
  int enableFlag;
  int setMode; 
  char* dbFile;
  IP2Location* ip2locObj;
} ip2location_server_config;

module AP_MODULE_DECLARE_DATA IP2Location_module;

static apr_status_t ip2location_cleanup(void *cfgdata) {
  // cleanup code here, if needed
  return APR_SUCCESS;
}

static void ip2location_child_init(apr_pool_t *p, server_rec *s) {
  apr_pool_cleanup_register(p, NULL, ip2location_cleanup, ip2location_cleanup);
}

static int ip2location_post_read_request(request_rec *r) {
  char* ipaddr;
  ip2location_server_config* config;
  IP2LocationRecord* record;
  char buff[20];

  config = (ip2location_server_config*)
                    ap_get_module_config(r->server->module_config, &IP2Location_module);

  if(!config->enableFlag)
    return OK;

  ipaddr = r->connection->remote_ip;
  record = IP2Location_get_all(config->ip2locObj, ipaddr);
  if(record) {
    if(config->setMode & ENV_SET_MODE) {
      apr_table_set(r->subprocess_env,
```

I tried to change this line:

```
  ipaddr = r->connection->remote_ip;
```

to

```
  ipaddr = r->header_in('X-Forwarded-For');
```

It would not compile and shot out errors that

In function 'ip2location_post_read_request': 
error: 'request_rec' has no member named 'header_in'
warning character constant too long for its type

I am not sure if there is a simple fix I am overlooking?  Thanks!

Comment: So does it have a member called `header_in`? Anyway, a string literal is written with double quotes, like `"X-Forwarded-For"`.

Comment: I'd bet that the code is C, and therefore `request_rec` doesn't have methods at all.

Comment: THanks for the tips, I loked at httpd.h, because I think that is what that ipaddr lines is calling and do not see it:  `**
 * @brief Structure to store things which are per connection
 */
struct conn_rec {
    /** Pool associated with this connection */
    apr_pool_t *pool;
    /** Physical vhost this conn came in on */
    server_rec *base_server;
    /** used by http_vhost.c */
    void *vhost_lookup_data;

    /* Information about the connection itself */
    

    /** Client's IP address */
    char *remote_ip;
    `

Comment: I do see the following in httpd.h:                                  `struct request_rec { /** MIME header environment from the request */
    apr_table_t *headers_in;`    that is the only line that I see headers_in mentioned at all.

Comment: also if i try to compile after chaning to double quotes and headers_in I get following error now mod_ip2location.c: In function 'ip2location_post_read_request':
mod_ip2location.c:61: error: called object 'r->headers_in' is not a function

Comment: @BoPersson I was looking at this link [link](http://thomas.eibner.dk/apache/table.html) would this code work then: `ipaddr = apr_table_get(r->headers_in, "X-Forwarded-For");`

Comment: That's not the proper way to dereference `headers_in` - try something like `apr_table_get(r->headers_in, "X-Forwarded-Host")`. Here's a doc on the Apache API that might be helpful - http://thomas.eibner.dk/apache/table.html